# First job likely to be remote due to COVID-19: tips needed

Tags: company-culture, employer-relations, first-job, covid-19, team-building

I am starting my carrer just now (currently applying for my first job after finishing my MSc degree), and the jobs I applied to are 100%, mostly or at least partly remote (I am applying for technological roles in company offices).

Since I have never had any work experience, the situation itself of "first job" would already require a lot of learning and adaptation (I have never had to adapt my self to a job in an office, to interiorize a company's culture, to establish relationships with a team and supervisors, etc etc). Due to the pandemic, I will have to not only learn all this, but also to do it 100% or partly remotely.

Does anyone have any tips in how to sucessfuly integrate myself in a team and in a company without physically being present in the office? I believe many more people in this forum may be in the same situation as me, so inputs are much appreciated!

Comment: I agree that there will be some challenges - that said, the fact that you already know that you'll need to "adapt [your]self to a job in an office, to interiorize a company's culture, to establish relationships with a team and supervisors, etc" makes me think you'll be just fine!  Good luck.

Comment: I hope you are right! @dan.mwasuser2321368 Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just some quick advice:

In a physical office, lots of interpersonal communication just 'happens'.

People go grab a coffee, and stop over at the new guy's desk on the way back to say hello and introduce themselves.

Conversations happen with people in your vicinity that you might be included in automatically or you can easily join.

People might invite you out for coffee/lunch/to show you the area.

etc. etc.

Working remotely, none of this happens unless you (and ideally your manager) *make it happen*.

Make it an explicit priority of yours to interact with different people at least every day, every other day, every week, etc.

For instance you could schedule a daily 15m call with your manager / coworkers you're working closely with.

Best of luck!

Comment: That is what makes me worried! The "coffee conversations" factor... the ones that don't happen remotely! What do you think is the best approach to interact with coworkers for someone new? To suggest it in a group meeting and straightforwardly say I would like to get to know them better on a regular basis to integrate myself? To simply ask someone closer if they would want to set it up?

Comment: Tip #1 would be to ask your manager for help making this happen. Tip #2 would be to individually message/email people in your immediate team and say something like "hey, I'm Johanna, I'm the new [X]. Seeing as we're all remote getting a coffee together isn't going to happen, so can we do a quick call sometime instead?"

Comment: Thank you for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Most of your perceived issues don't exist unless you invent them for yourself.

Your main problem will be staying motivated and working. It's extremely easy when working remotely to slack off and procrastinate. And the company will be looking for people doing that.

The company will have professionals outlining procedures and keeping everyone in touch. Follow their lead until you know your way around your role. They know it's your first job and they will factor that in when integrating you into a team.

Comment: I strongly disagree. It may be easy for someone already in the company, and to someone who has been working for a long time. From the people I know, when people enter their first job they are always stressed and worried, and many have difficulties in interiorizing immediately the company's culture, or even the "working routine", simply because it is something very different from which we have done before. Naturally, the "remote" characteristic enhances all those preocupations.

Comment: Nontheless, thank you for the input! I hope they, as you said, do take into account how it would be my first job! Hopefully I will be less stressed out when I actually start the job and know for sure how things will play out

Comment: Yes, stressing is a non productive waste of energy, meet everything positively and you'll be fine. There's nothing particularly difficult about getting settled in your first job. Mostly just your attitude to things.

Answer (score 0):

Set up yourself a dedicated place in your home where you work. I find this helps manage the work/home aspect of things and stick to it.

Otherwise integrating in an organisation is quite variable as there may or may not be a compagny identity. If there are unofficials ways to communicate with outers in more 'private' groups or such things it might be a good idea to ask around for such things.

This depend on a lot of things and in these conditions you might need to be the one stepping forward, doing live meetings with others to become more familiar with your peers and create a connection. Otherwise I feel like people will be less reluctant to go to you to show you how things work in the current settings.

In such case you may need to take the initiatives and contact people that you may work with and ask them if they have the them or when they would be available for a live meeting as part of your integration in the organisation.

Comment: Thank you for the advise! I agree that I will need to be the one to step forward. However, setting presential meetings with others may not be the best idea due to the current pandemic situation, and due to the restrictions of maximum number of people that can be together in my country, it may even be illegal...

Comment: @Johanna when I'm talking about live-meetings I am talking about remote meetings such as teams or zooms, with video and audio as opposed to simply chatting. I'm just not sure what is the adequate term, remote meetings maybe?

Comment: That makes sense! Do you believe it would be viewed as "weird" if I was straightforward and asked them to do some remote meetings in order to get to know them better?

Comment: @Johanna it's normal for someone new to get their bearings. Just state that you are new and would like to know about their work, their responsibility, their challenges, etc. You can ask your direct manager on advise on who you should contact. Don't contact random people but familiarise yourself with common and potential people that you will have to work with. In my organisation its normal and if people have the time they usually are happy to demonstrate their work.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs!